# What does this text in the ice say?

Tags: paper-mario

I'm playing Paper Mario for the N64. Just got to Shiver City and I noticed the ice has text in it. What does this say? Is it documented anywhere?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Figured it out. It's nothing - just a graphical error with Mupen64. Here it is again after I talk to the toads next to the pond. It must be overlaying some text that either the green penguin or the penguin blocking the east gate said.

[image]

Comment: It's interesting. I managed to figure out some of the words in your OP. The first line (it's flipped upside down): "-ave (save/have?) him to- (ta-?)". The second line: "-hing (thing/something?) near-". Since it's a graphical glitch it's likely it's part of a conversation you have with an NPC/

Comment: For the record (minor spoilers), [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgWE84Fpk-o) shows how the ice is *supposed* to look. Mupen64 appears to be mixing up which texture to use for the ice surface.